# режим «Для разработчиков» в Android 4.1.2

Tags: android

Как включить режим «Для разработчиков» в Android 4.1.2. Везде показывается с версии 4.2+, но раньше не могу найти

Answer (score 0, accepted):

До 4.2 в настройках есть опция разработчиков, которую нужно включить, а в 4.2+ нужно нажать 7 раз на номер версии.

Answer (score 3):

Насколько я помню, надо в `Settings` найти `Developer options`, и там включить. Если его нет, то надо зайти в `About phone` и покликать несколько (раз десять, не помню) на `Build number`, после этого `Developer options` появится.

Comment: второй вариант это в версии 4.2+

Comment: я тебе плюсик дал, дай и ты мне)

Comment: м? у тебя-то тогда в чем сложность?

Comment: уже ни в чем) у меня android 4.1.2, оказывается здесь легче чем в 4.2

Comment: Да да в меню о телефоне есть пункт номер сборки. Вот на него покликать 5 раз